# changes introduced by branch X, since it diverged from branch Y

Tags: git

What's a good, concise, easily-remembered way to ask for "changes introduced by branch X, since it diverged from branch Y"?  I often find myself doing this:

```
$ git diff --stat $(git merge-base master HEAD)..
```

But it seems like there's got to be a shorthand for that not involving bash-isms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The triple-dot revision notation `X...Y` automatically computes the merge-base of commits `X` and `Y`.  Normally it means (as [`gitrevisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) notes) "the set of commits reachable from either rev but not from both revs".

For `git diff`, however, the [meaning is altered](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html):

> ```
>   git diff [--options] <commit>...<commit> [--] [<path>...]
>        This form is to view the changes on the branch containing and up to
>        the second <commit>, starting at a common ancestor of both
>        <commit>. "git diff A...B" is equivalent to "git diff
>        $(git-merge-base A B) B". You can omit any one of <commit>, which
>        has the same effect as using HEAD instead.
> ```

Meanwhile, in `git diff`, plain `..` is *also* altered, and means the same as specifying each revision on either side of the `..` separately.

So:

```
git diff --stat $(git merge-base master HEAD)..
```

is the same as:

```
git diff --stat $(git merge-base master HEAD)..HEAD
```

which is the same as:

```
git diff --stat $(git merge-base master HEAD) HEAD
```

which is the same as:

```
git diff --stat master...HEAD
```

which is the same as:

```
git diff --stat master...
```

which is your shortest short-hand.